# How to populate count number from another schema on Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two schema: **Product** and **Region**

**Product**:

```
_id,
name,
price,
region_id
```

**Region**:

```
 _id,
 region_name
```

I want to get region result which includes

```
_id, 
region_name, 
**the number of products from the region**
```

Using Region.find() then I got

```
[ { _id: XXX, region_name: 'ABC' }, ... ]
```

Should I use populate() or other methods?

My setup: Node JS, Express, Mongoose

Thanks!

Comment: You should use `$lookup` aggregation here. Populate will not work here as expected.

Comment: Answer doesn't work for you?